# prompt not a function and unexpeced token else issues in basic code -- n00b

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript via pluralSight and using firefox scratchpad and google js scratch in the dev tools and am running into these errors (even when copying the example code exactly). I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, any insight would be great!

Thanks

Issue 1:

prompt is not a function:
[image: prompt is not a function]

Issue 2:

Unexpected token else:
[image: prompt is not a function]

Comment: use a browser to test browser code... fiddle, codepen, et el

Comment: Please don't post a picture of code. It makes it so people just won't try to reproduce the error and troubleshoot it. Post the actual text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1:

`prompt` function should be defined somewhere like:

```
var prompt = function() { /* logic */} // prompt is not defined
```

or:

```
function prompt () { /* logic */ }
```

Issue 2: after `if ()` (in line 4) there shouldn't be `;`

Comment: The `prompt()` function is probably supposed to refer to the normal browser built-in.

Comment: Might be - or it supposed to be defined and output something with console.log - there's no information about it. I've wrote what I think might be helpful.

Comment: Sure, I don't disagree; it's not super-clear what's going on. You're definitely right about the semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- 
it must be some sort of browser default, as the example code doesn't have prompt as a variable and it was not included anywhere in the instructions... 

and issue 2, resolved thanks!